# Remove string from the last full stop

Tags: c#, html, string, join, character

I want to remove all remaining characters from the last full stop. how do I achieve this?

From - "I am making dinner. On 12.01.20. Would you like to join. Yes/No"
To - "I am making dinner. On 12.01.20. Would you like to join"

Comment: Can I have n example code please?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [LastIndexOf(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?view=net-5.0) to find the index of the last occurence of a character. You can then use [SubString(...)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.substring?view=net-5.0) to extract the string from the begining up to the character.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @Dtorto 1986 I omitted an example by purpose since it should be rather trivial to implement yourself. If you have difficulty understanding some specific issue I can provide more details, but the documentation in the linked methods should provide enough to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Get Substring from 0 to last index of `.`,

```
var str = "I am making dinner. On 12.01.20. Would you like to join. Yes/No"
var output = str.Substring(0, str.LastIndexOf('.') + 1); //+1 to print Period(.) at the end
Console.WriteLine(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all we can use `string.Split` with the `"."` symbol. To seperate all elements of our string into sentences.

```cs
string example = "I am making dinner. On 12.01.20. Would you like to join. Yes/No";

// Seperate string into multiple string at the symbol.
List<string> list = example.Split('.').ToList();
```

After we've done that we can now check if the last element contains the wanted symbol. If it does we remove it from the `List<string>`.

```cs
// Remove the last element in our List if it doesn't contain the wanted symbol.
if (!list[list.Count -1].Contains('.')) {
    list.RemoveAt(list.Count -1);
}
```

Now that the last part not containing the symbol is removed we can `string.Join` our `List<string>` into one `string`.

We also need to re-add the wanted symbol because it has been cut with `string.Split`.

```cs
// Join List into new string and add the wanted symbol after each element in the List.
string concat = string.Join(".", list.ToArray());
```